# Jump with Ctrl-O/I doesn't work in my Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I use GVim 7.2 on Windows XP. In my installation some of the jump commands don't work, such as  +<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, whereas `:jump` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> work.

What might be the reason for this? I checked my `_vimrc` file for a remapping of `<C-o>` but there doesn't seem to be any remapping. Where should I look into to find the reason of this problem?

Comment: what does `:verbose map <c-o>` tell? This will tell you when it was last mapped, and in what script. You might have plugins that remap that combination.

Comment: If `mswin.vim` is included (which it is, by default), it does some wonky things with various `Ctrl-` combos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get more unix-like behaviour of vim on Windows you need comment out these lines from `C:\Program files\Vim\_vimrc` file:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim 
behave mswin
```

`CTRL-O` should start working after restart of vim.