# jump to previous location doesn't work in vim

Tags: vim

For some strange reason ctrl-i/o combination to jump to previous/next location doesn't work for me.

As suggested in the comment to OP
[Jump with Ctrl-O/I doesn't work in my Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192545/jump-with-ctrl-o-i-doesnt-work-in-my-vim)

`:verbose map <C-o>` and `:verbose map <C-i>` gives me "no mapping found".

How do i restore these key mappings ?

EDIT : This is my vimrc http://pastebin.com/bX2NkNgz

Comment: have you tried running vim with `-u NONE` to see if any plugins are causing this gassy behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
:verbose map <C-o>
:verbose map <C-i>
```

Or you can press <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-i</kbd> and <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> respectively

(if on Windows, you might need to use <kbd>C-q</kbd> instead of <kbd>C-v</kbd>)

---

PS. Are you on windows? If so, try scrapping `behave mswin` and `source mswin.vim` and similar from `$MYVIMRC`. Restart

Comment: sorry i meant :verbose map <C-o> and <C-i> in the question.  I will edit it now. The output is still "no mapping found". No, I am using ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

`<C-o>` and `<C-i>` are built-ins: you won't see them with `:map`. Same for any other `d` or `zM`.

Just to be sure, are you in *normal* mode? Are you using Vim in "easy" mode? Could you show us the content of your vimrc?

Comment: Yes, i am in normal mode. I've edited the post to include vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

I was in same situation.

Do you use tmux or other terminal multiplexer?

In my case, I overwrote vim key mapping blow code, so I remove below code, then finally `<C-o>` , `<C-i>` works well.

`bind-key -n C-o run "tmux select-pane -l || tmux select-pane -t :.+"`